# How can data be retrieved in Ethereum?

Tags: solidity, struct

I am a newbie to the blockchain world. I have written contract code in solidity and tested in remix. I am able to get the list values from the struct, but I am confused on how I can get a single record from the blockchain.

How could the input data which I previously set be retrieved using solidity?

Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: You should share the code you have written, show us the output you are getting, and then tell us the output you want/expect instead.

Answer (score 0):

You should do a getter function for that. If the data is inside a struct you can only retrive all of them, but you could do a getter for it

```
struct MyData {
    uint a;
    uint b;
}

MyData public myData;

function setData(uint a, uint b) external {
    myData.a = a;
    myData.b = b;
}

function getData() external view returns(uint a, uint b) {
    a = myData.a;
    b = myData.b;
}
```

Comment: That is correct, but since myData is declared as public, it already has a getter, if you call getData() and myData() and you'll get the same result.

Comment: @Ricardo Guilherme Schmidt On what basis that you are getting a,b values .There is any way that to get the values by passing id or transcation id. to get a single record

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `a single record`?

Comment: Yes, i mean single record @nikos fotiadis